# Python: How to fix "pyenv: bash: command not found"

Tags: python, bash, pyenv

I use `pyenv` to manage my Python environments and I get the following when simply running `bash`.

```
$ bash
pyenv: bash: command not found
```

I was trying to troubleshoot why `pipenv shell` failed with the above error, which is how I found out even `bash` wasn't working. I tried updating `pipenv` via `brew` and ran `pyenv rehash` to regenerate the shims. And `bash` is definitely present.

```
$ which bash
/bin/bash
```

I expected that if `pyenv` doesn't find a command, the subsequent paths specified by the `PATH` environment variable will be searched. Interestingly if I execute some non-existant command I don't get a `pyenv` error.

```
$ someboguscommand
-bash: someboguscommand: command not found
```

This suggests to me that `pyenv` doesn't even search for a matching command in this case and the subsequent paths in `PATH` are searched, so there must be some special handling with `bash`.

Comment: What does `type bash` say?

Comment: `$ type bash`

`bash is hashed (/bin/bash)`

Comment: This suggests that the problem is with a command in your init files, such as `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`. You can run `bash -x` to show a debug trace of what's going on, and where it starts to fail. Running `bash` by itself probably worked in spite of the error, and is only showing a warning about a failing `pyenv` command in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` while otherwise giving you a working shell.

Comment: Better, I'd suggest `PS4=':$BASHPID:${BASH_SOURCE##*/}:$LINENO+' bash -x`, to log a process ID, source file and line number with each command in the trace log. Compare the `BASHPID` in those logs with the one in your starting shell and you have a conclusive answer as to whether the error is in- or out-of-process.

Comment: BTW, at the risk of drifting out of advice into advocacy, personally, I'm much happier using [Nix](https://nixos.org/nix/) for managing development environments -- which lets you control not just which Python modules are in-scope for each shell or project, but also versions of other executables and libraries; meaning you can have, say, bash 5 in one environment, and bash 3.2 in another; or a Python built against one version of zlib or sqlite in one, and a different version in another; etc -- likewise, it supports managing Ruby/Node/Haskell/etc. compilers/interpreters/libraries.

Comment: I would start by looking at my .profile, .bashrc and similar files. The init code for pyenv is in their and seems to be broken. Maybe remove that and setup pyenv again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I had the following line in my `.bashrc`, which was being invoked when running `bash`. It's a line that I no longer need:

```
. virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

This was in turn invoking pyenv's virtualwrapper shim:

```
$ which virtualenvwrapper.sh
/Users/greg/.pyenv/shims/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

That's what caused the failure. I was able to identify this by running a debug trace with `bash`:

```
$ bash -x
+ . virtualenvwrapper.sh
++ set -e
++ '[' -n '' ']'
++ program=bash
++ [[ bash = \p\y\t\h\o\n* ]]
++ export PYENV_ROOT=/Users/greg/.pyenv
++ PYENV_ROOT=/Users/greg/.pyenv
++ exec /usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/1.2.13_1/libexec/pyenv exec bash
pyenv: bash: command not found
```

Thank you for the useful comments "that other guy", Charles Duffy, and rje!

Answer (score 9):

I had this issue when setting up **Python 3.8** on **CentOS** using **Pyenv**.

I was running into the error below when I run `pyenv install 3.8.2`:

```
pyenv: bash: command not found
```

**Here's how I solved it**:

The issue was pyenv was not added to the load path for my profile.

All I had to do was to do the following:

Open the `.bashrc` file in the home directory of my user:

```
sudo nano ~/.bashrc
```

Next, add the following add the bottom of the file and save:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

Finally, restart your terminal or run the command below to load the newly added paths into your current shell/terminal session:

```
exec "$SHELL"
```

Now when you run the command `pyenv install 3.8.2` it should work fine.

**Resources**: [Managing Multiple Python Versions With pyenv](https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/)

That's all.

**I hope this helps**